# Windows Phone 8 XAML Loading

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, load

I have an app with a pretty big XAML tree on the mainpage, which causes it to load slow (2 seconds to draw the screen), it doesn't even show the WP Toolkit page transition animations.
It doesn't appear to load slow on the emulator, it shows the transations perfectly as well.
On a phone (Lumia 1520) it takes some time to load each page tho. This happens on all pages, even with a smaller xaml tree.

Are there any ways to improve the xaml speed, like would it help to split the xaml items into usercontrols? Any tips are welcome.
Or why it works slower on the device than the emulator (WP8.1 512mb RAM).

Comment: Do you have much that is data-bound in the XAML?  It can help to do your view model loading/processing in a background thread, and also to load collections or properties piecemeal using a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Yes, it is databound (using GalaSoft MVVM). How would I load the viewmodel in a background thread?

Comment: Well, it is likely the view loading that is slow, and that has to be single threaded.  What you can do, though, is use a DispatcherTimer or a similar mechanism to set the data-bound view-model properties in chunks, rather than all at once.  (Note that I have no idea if this would help, since I don't know any details about your app.)

Comment: I can try that, but there aren't that many seperate objects to load. The objects that are loaded are quite large tho. My MainPage.xaml is 1172 lines with a lot of converters, I think that's the main issue. Because even if I disable all the ViewModel loading, it's still quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Windows Phone Application Analysis tool - you will find out what are the most time consuming tasks while loading the window.
You can find instructions on how to use it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215908%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)